# Model sharing vertices between in- and outside normals?

Tags: vertices, normals

I've been trying some stuff in Blender, I am however quite inexperienced. I found a free model online which I was trying some stuff with, like I've done before. However this model has a weird problem. As far as I can see it has some vertices which are both part of the inside normal and the outside normal. I've tried recalculating the normals and some other stuff I found on Google, but to no avail. Is there a way to fix this? Or is this a toss and try another one?

Thanks in advance.

Picture on Imgur: https://imgur.com/a/Gt1D4Yt

Blender project: [image]

Comment: It is a nightmare... It is discontinuous, some "interior" nodes are protruding outside, some nodes are shared by interior and exterior faces ! My advice is to try something else !

Comment: That's what I figured as well, I don't know where the designing party went wrong, but I figured it's horrid. Ah well, maybe I'll make one myself. Thanks!